# React Dynamic MultiSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and googling multi select is not turning up anything useful. What I currently have is a UI with a multi select, where a user can select a list of states. Now after state selection, a user can select cities based off of the states that they clicked above in a second multiselect. The states part is working, and here is the psuedo code for that piece.

```
import * as React from "react";
import {MultiSelect}



    type states = [
        states: string[]
        cities: string[]
    ]

    const [results, setStates] = React.useState<states>({
        states: []
        cities:[]
    )};
    
    const allStates = [
        "Utah",
        "Oregon",
        "Wisconsin"
    ]
    const allUtahCities = [
        "Salt Lake",
    ]
    const allOregonCities = [
        "Medford",
        "Portland
    ]

    return(
        <form>
            <MultiSelect
                placeholder = (intl.formatMessage("Please Select a State"))
                options = {allStates.map((x: string) => ({ label: x, value: x}))}
                values = {results.states}
                onItemsChange={(e) => (setField((prev) =>({...prev, states: e? e.map((i) => i.value) : []})))}          
            </MultiSelect>
        </form>
    
    );
```

What I would like to do, is instead of having a completely separate second multi select with a list of cities, is in the same multi select. If you select Utah, then Salt Lake will appear below it (and checked!) in the same drop down. I feel like I should be able to make an async call to refresh the list, but based off of googling this doesn't seem possible, so I am turning this query over to the internet incase I am missing something.

If people do not believe the above is possible. Is it possible to list Utah, with Salt Lake below it in the drop down, and if you select Utah, Salt Lake will be selected automatically?

If that is not possible is it possible to have a multi select where all of the options are selected automatically? I feel like this should be possible but I admittedly I haven't googled that last one.

Comment: You should add the code for your MultiSelect component.

Comment: Apologies friend, but I included the multi select for states section. Are you asking for the cities part too?

Comment: https://ant.design/components/select#select-demo-multiple https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#multiple-select

Comment: Just to be sure, you are expecting that when you select the state in the dropdown, its cities will also get fetched in the dropdown list and get selected. Am I right?

Comment: @Chinz, yes that is exactly what I am hoping for.

Comment: @UjinT34 thank you for those references let me take a look at them.

Comment: @user3782816 I personally think that having the "cities" and "states" and values in the same dropdown might not be a good idea and can increase the complexity of your component. As a suggestion, you might try multi-selectors with custom "option" and "search" feature where you can search your state name and all the cities with that state name will appear and you can select them from there.

Comment: Also, if you have seen a similar implementation somewhere as you mentioned, please share that to get a better idea of the exact UI that you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your data you could have a variation on a recursive component.

Here the data is an array of objects, and each object can be selected and have optional children.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ stateData }) {  
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(stateData);
  
  // Currently supports selecting state and cities, but
  // could be rewritten to utilise any number of levels of children
  function handleClick(e) {

    // On click grab the name of the object from
    // the element's dataset
    const { dataset: { name } } = e.target;
    
    // map over the data in state and if the obj name
    // matches the name in the dataset change "selected, and
    // do the same with its children, otherwise turn off "selected"
    setData(prev => {
      return prev.map(obj => {
        if (obj.name === name) {
          return {
            ...obj,
            selected: true,
            children: obj.children.map(child => {
              return { ...child, selected: !child.selected };    
            })
          };
        }
        return { ...obj, selected: false };
      });
    });
  }
    
  return (
    <main>
      <MultiSelect
        data={data}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </main>
  );

}

// If an object has children call the MultiSelect component
// with _that_ data
function MultiSelect({ data, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(obj => {
      
        // If the data object is selected and
        // it has a children prop which is an array
        // with at least one element in it...
        const showChildren =
          obj.selected &&
          obj.children &&
          obj.children.length > 0;
      
        return (
          <li
            key={obj.id}
            className={obj.selected ? 'selected' : ''}
            data-name={obj.name}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >{obj.name}
          {showChildren && <MultiSelect data={obj.children} />}
          </li>
        );

      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

const stateData = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Utah',
    selected: false,
    children: [
      { id: '1.1', name: 'Salt Lake' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Oregon',
    selected: false,
    children: [
      { id: '2.1', name: 'Medford', selected: false },
      { id: '2.2', name: 'Portland', selected: false }
    ]
  }
];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example stateData={stateData}/>);
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding-left: 1rem;}
li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.selected { text-decoration: underline; color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that looks really neat. I am having internet issues at the moment so haven't been able to try it out, but thank you for the help.

Comment: If I wished to make Portland checked, but to uncheck Medford would I just need to write a new function to be called inside your setData function?

Comment: That would probably involve a different solution with a different approach to how state works and how items are selected. You may want to ask a new question to narrow down this new functionality if you run into problems. @user3782816