# React multiselect with option selected by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Last week I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78093133/react-dynamic-multiselect) about multi select drop downs in React. What I have is the below code. In one drop down you have a list of states. You can select multiple states. In the next drop down you have a list of the cities in those states, which are selected by default. What I need is the ability to deselect a subset of those cities and then add them to a variable. Implementing the drop down with the states and then populating the cities and having them be checked was simple enough, but unchecking some of the cities after they are selected is proving more nuanced and as I don't have enough experience with react... well here I am. If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it.

As a bonus question, how does an element that you pass into a multi select, know its selected? I understand the concept of clicking an element and that click event passing the value into a desired array/list/etc., but where is the state of that variable persisted and how do you access it?

edit by "Next dropdown" I mean after the re-render with the states and the cities below the states. If it is more practical to handle my requirement with a second drop down that can also work, but even then I wasn't able to make much progress.

Code copied from user Andy

```
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ stateData }) {  
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(stateData);
  
  // Currently supports selecting state and cities, but
  // could be rewritten to utilise any number of levels of children
  function handleClick(e) {

    // On click grab the name of the object from
    // the element's dataset
    const { dataset: { name } } = e.target;
    
    // map over the data in state and if the obj name
    // matches the name in the dataset change "selected, and
    // do the same with its children, otherwise turn off "selected"
    setData(prev => {
      return prev.map(obj => {
        if (obj.name === name) {
          return {
            ...obj,
            selected: true,
            children: obj.children.map(child => {
              return { ...child, selected: !child.selected };    
            })
          };
        }
        return { ...obj, selected: false };
      });
    });
  }
    
  return (
    <main>
      <MultiSelect
        data={data}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </main>
  );

}

// If an object has children call the MultiSelect component
// with _that_ data
function MultiSelect({ data, handleClick }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(obj => {
      
        // If the data object is selected and
        // it has a children prop which is an array
        // with at least one element in it...
        const showChildren =
          obj.selected &&
          obj.children &&
          obj.children.length > 0;
      
        return (
          <li
            key={obj.id}
            className={obj.selected ? 'selected' : ''}
            data-name={obj.name}
            onClick={handleClick}
          >{obj.name}
          {showChildren && <MultiSelect data={obj.children} />}
          </li>
        );

      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

const stateData = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Utah',
    selected: false,
    children: [
      { id: '1.1', name: 'Salt Lake' }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Oregon',
    selected: false,
    children: [
      { id: '2.1', name: 'Medford', selected: false },
      { id: '2.2', name: 'Portland', selected: false }
    ]
  }
];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example stateData={stateData}/>);
```

Comment: I suggest creating a example sandbox and then linking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand the concept of clicking an element and that click event passing the value into a desired array/list/etc., but where is the state of that variable persisted and how do you access it?

React, when given a task to render a component, calls the function responsible for it and puts on screen whatever aforementioned function returns. A pure JavaScript function can't persist any state between any two calls (let's ignore globals for now), so this is what `useState` hook is for. This is where the persistence happens. If you set an object using `setData`, it will be returned in `data` next time `Example` is called. It sort of resembles injection - state is injected into component-function. Try logging to console:

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState(stateData);
  console.debug("data", data);
```

and see what sits there - it's a list of objects like this:

```json
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Utah",
      "selected":false,
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"1.1",
            "name":"Salt Lake"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Oregon",
      "selected":false,
      "children":[
         {
            "id":"2.1",
            "name":"Medford",
            "selected":false
         },
         {
            "id":"2.2",
            "name":"Portland",
            "selected":false
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

You create it in `handleClick`. Notice the `selected` flag: when it's true, a list of cities will appear because of this fragment:

```js
        const showChildren =
          obj.selected && obj.children && obj.children.length > 0;

//(a couple of lines omitted...)
            {showChildren && <MultiSelect data={obj.children} />}
```

So whenever you want to deselect anything, you just change correspondent flag to `false`. This is basically what happens in the following fragment:

```js
return { ...obj, selected: false };
```

the clicked thing is deselected. Remember to **never edit the state directly - use setter** and make sure new object is set, because if you set the same object again, React won't rerender assuming nothing has changed.

As a summary, in order to create what you described in the title: "React multiselect with option selected by default", all you have to do is to change intitial state by putting `selected: true` to whatever you want to be selected by default, for example the first element:

```js
const stateData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Utah",
    selected: true,
    children: [{ id: "1.1", name: "Salt Lake" }],
  },
//etc.
```

I strongly recommend to read official docs on `useState`: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState

Comment: Thank you for the info I feel much better informed about the handling of clicks now and the reference.